# How to view changes done to the git repo in brackets or other text editor

Tags: git, github, repository, pull

Me and a classmate recently started working on a project via git and we are trying to figure out the best way to see what changes has been done to the repository before we pull. We managed once to get the brackets to open up and display all the changes i had made to the document exactly like we wanted but now we cant replicate or remember how we did..

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you've fetched the latest changes in the remote repo (this will download the changes, but not apply them like `git pull` would):

`git fetch`

Then, you can do a `git diff` to check the changes:

`git diff [branch] [remote]/[branch]`

eg 
`git diff master origin/master`

Hope this helps. For future reference, it's always useful to [look at a cheatsheet](https://services.github.com/on-demand/downloads/github-git-cheat-sheet.pdf) if you haven't already.

Comment: This is knew, currently we are doing this but it displays the changes in the terminal. What i would like is more or less is for the changes to show inside my text editor such as atom / brackets / visual studio..

Comment: Ah, sorry for the misunderstanding. For future reference I'd suggest using capital letters for proper nouns, as I interpreted 'the brackets' to mean the literal characters (you don't need to write 'the' before, either).

It looks there are [extensions that will do what you're looking for](https://github.com/zaggino/brackets-git). The green bars in the screenshots are showing when new lines are added that differ from the head.